# A function generating particle-in-a-box eigenfunctions

Tags: function-construction, physics, trigonometry

This function sequence is defined over $\left[-\frac{L}{2},\frac{L}{2}\right]$ (all elements are valued 0 outside this interval):

$$\psi_n(x)=\begin{cases}\sqrt{\frac2{L}}\sin{\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)} & n \text{ even} \\ \sqrt{\frac2{L}}\cos{\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)} & n \text{ odd}\end{cases}$$

I would like to create a *Mathematica* function that takes a natural number $N$ as a single parameter, and returns the corresponding function definition from the sequence. Looks like it boils down to substituting $n=N$ and substituting $\sin\oplus\cos=\begin{cases}\sin & N \text{ even} \\ \cos & N \text{ odd}\end{cases}.$

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Could you please post the Mathematica code you've written so far?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you mean this?

I like purely algebraic forms;

```
g[n_, L_, x_] := 
   (1 + (-1)^n) Sqrt[2/L] Sin[n Pi x/L]/2 + 
   (1 - (-1)^n) Sqrt[2/L] Cos[n Pi x/L]/2
```

But `Piecewise` will work too:

```
f[n_, L_, x_] := Piecewise[{
                   {Sqrt[2/L] Sin[n Pi x/L], EvenQ[n]}, 
                   {Sqrt[2/L] Cos[n Pi x/L], OddQ[n]}
                  }]
```

Comment: +1 for the un-traditional  way of using `Piecewise[]`

Comment: So it need not be piecewise after all.. Beautiful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can exploit `Mod[]` + trigonometric identities for a very compact expression:

```
ψ[n_Integer?NonNegative, x_, L_: 1] :=
  Sqrt[2/L] Sin[n π x/L + π Mod[n, 2]/2]
```

Comment: …and you can use `UnitBox[]` to impose the condition of being zero outside the desired interval.